# I am having a doubt

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, verbs

> **I have a doubt**
>
> **I am having a doubt**

So far as I know **have** can not be used in the sense of possession.

So I think the  second  sentence is wrong.

> **I am having a good time** is correct because having is used in the sense of experiencing.
>
> **Is  I am having a doubt/question** right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which variety of English you are talking.

"A doubt" meaning "a question or problem" is almost confined to Indian English; and the use of "I am having" in this sense is also almost confined to Indian English.

So "I am having a doubt" is found in Indian English, but rare anywhere else.

[There are senses in which "I am having" is used in other Englishes, for example "I am having a party next week" (future intention), "I am having palpitations" (current inner experience), and in fact "I am having doubts about X" (also current inner experience).]

Comment: As a native Australian English speaking, I might say "I have a doubt", "I have doubts" and "I'm having doubts", but not "I'm having a doubt".

Comment: I've heard @I have a doubt' almost exclusively from Indian English speakers, in the UK. I have heard it from an English English speaker, but she was making a joke.

Comment: "When Australians say that they say I have a doubt." - I don't think so, I think they say "I have a question."

Comment: Searching the GloWbE corpus for "I have a doubt", it shows up 39 times from Indian sites, 18 from Pakistan, Sri Lanka, and Bangladesh, and 38 from the rest of the Anglosphere. It's Indian English.